# Maclaurin Series for $\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Is there a trick to finding the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ fast? Vaguely, I recall this being some sort of inverse hyperbolic function, but I'm not sure about which one, and what its derivatives are. This is a past exam question and I would like to know, should something similar appear again, if there is a quick method of finding this series without using inverse hyperbolic functions. The derivatives of this look absolutely painful to calculate, although easy at $x=0$, but I'm not sure if I could easily see a pattern for the $n$-th derivative at $0$.

Comment: It's the inverse of [$\sinh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest method: note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=(1+x^2)^{-1/2}.
$$
This last can be expressed through a binomial series; you can then integrate term by term, and solve for the constant of integration, to get the series you want.

Comment: Haha, of course! I calculated the first derivative but failed to see the simplification so I thought it's much uglier! Thanks.

Comment: Sure, couldn't accept straight away because I accepted one recently.

Comment: Note that the derivative is an even function, so alternating terms of the Maclaurin Series will be 0.